# Generically typed interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics

I came across the following code in our code base:

```
public interface ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone();
}

public class MyObject : ICloneable<MyObject>
{
    public Stuff SomeStuff { get; set; }

    T Clone()
    {
        return new MyObject { SomeStuff = this.SomeStuff };
    }
}
```

The pattern of using a generic interface and then doing `class A : Interface<A>` looks pretty bizarre to me. I have a feeling it's either useless or that it could be changed into something less intricated.
Can someone explain if this is right/wrong, and how it should be changed?

Comment: Implementation of the `Clone` should return `MyObject` not `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this same pattern in the framework for `IEquatable<T>`.  The most frequent use case for this is writing a generic method where you constrain the generic parameter type to implement the interface.  This then allows you to write code in terms of a statically typed method `Equals<T>`.  Another example is `IComparable<T>`, which is very handy for implementing methods relying on sorting without having to use the older style of providing an external Comparator class.  For instance, the default comparison mechanism for the LINQ `OrderBy` method uses `IComparable<T>`, if it's available.  In both of these cases, it's very natural to say that an instance of a type is comparable or equatable to other instances of the same type.

Comment: good point, it definitely makes sense it that case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is called a [Prototype object creation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern). Usually it is used to do a deep cloning of objects (that is if `Stuff` is a reference type then it should also be cloned).

Comment: almaz, what I don't get is why make the interface generic

Comment: So that you get a typed instance. If you declare interface as non-generic, return value would be `object`. When you're cloning a `MyObject` instance it's logical to have a `MyObject` return value

Comment: almaz: yes I understand the intent, but isnt'it disturbing to have `class A : I<A>`.

Comment: and doesn't it violate the prototype object creation pattern to know the type of A? I mean that `((ICloneable) obj).Clone()` doesn't need to know the type of the underlying object. But `((ICloneable<MyObject>) obj).Clone()` does know the object, so why not create the method MyObject Clone() directly on the object itself, and not use any interface...

Comment: If you mark type parameter as covariant (`public interface ICloneable<out T>`) then you would be able to do the following assignment `ICloneable<object> generalClonable = new MyObject();`

Comment: ok, but if MyObject was ICloneable, I could do that too

Comment: Generic interface gives you ability to use result either generally (as `object`) or as specific type (when you know it). Non-generic `ICloneable` interface will require you to cast result in case you know the type.